# VBA runtime error 91, object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, runtime

I am trying to copy data from excel to ppt. Below is part of my code...i am getting error at the line mentioned below. The issue is that it runs most of the time but it starts throwing error suddenly. Please help me identify the reason for the same

```
 Dim pptChart As Chart
    Dim pptChartData As ChartData
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim wbk, wbk_copy As Workbook
    Dim wbk_paste As Worksheet
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim date_string As String
    
    filepath = ActivePresentation.Path
    
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wbk_copy = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath & "\development file.xlsm", True, False)
    'xlApp.Visible = True
    date_string = (wbk_copy.Worksheets("Data").Cells(10, 2))
    existing_date_string = (wbk_copy.Worksheets("Data").Cells(11, 2))
    wbk_copy.Close True
    Set xlApp = Nothing   
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
      If shp.Name = "Title1" Then

        '##### Getting error on below line ####
          m = shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(existing_date_string).Characters.Start 
                    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(m).InsertBefore (date_string)
                    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(existing_date_string).Delete
      End If
```

Comment: `sld` isn't set anywhere.

Comment: `m = shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(existing_date_string).Characters.Start` You are assuming that the `.Find` will return something. Break that part into two parts and then only if the `.Find` is successful, use `.Characters.Start `

Comment: The `existing_date_string` isn't found in the TextRange. The error occurs because the `Start` property can't be read from the `Find` object that would only exist if the `existing_date_string` would be found. Find out what that string is and why it isn't found where you expect it. More generally speaking, you should always ensure that objects that you create actually were created before starting to use them. That's the better coding practise.

Comment: Feel free to post and answer and accept it.